# Interfacing to end-of-line resistor in security system

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, resistance, security

Off-the-shelf security consoles utilize an end-of-line resistor to monitor the integrity of the cable runs, usually a 2 kΩ resistor.

Is there a more or less standard interface circuit that most of them use to sense the line resistance? Or does everybody do their own thing? I am thinking of maybe building my own.

- Voltage divider + 2 op-amps?
- Current source + 2 op-amps?
- Voltage divider + ADC + MCU?
- Current source + ADC + MCU?

Comment: connecting long wires directly to a microcontroller is a bad idea CMOS doesn't like lightning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a voltage divider with comparators instead of op-amps,  eg LM339 is way cheap and has 4 comparator sections.  the outputs can be paralleled if you don't need to tell the difference between resistance too high and resistance too low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdjT66.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

here is shown an alarm zone circuit with terminating resistor and a mixture of normally closed and normally open sensors  and the circuitry inside the alarm

R1,R2,R3 make a voltage divider with two taps, one at 45% and the other at 55% this voltage divider can be shared with the other zones in the alarm.

so long as the external alarm circuit presents about 2K ohms the divider it forms with R4 it will give a result between these two voltages and both comparitors will be in the high state in this state their output is undriven and R8 pulls the ~ERROR output high

U1 takes power from the alarm battery (12V or 24V) this means the accetable window is a volt or more so a few hundered millivolts of inductive interferance on the alarm loop will not trigger the alarm.

The pull-up R8 connects to the microcontroller power supply making the comparator output compatible with the microcontroller input voltage,  if the microcontroller input has an internal pull-up this part can be omitted.

Comment: Great. Do we need to worry about long wires and lightning with LM339? It doesn't have CMOS inputs, and it has "limited built-in ESD protection". At what cable length would you consider adding external clamping diodes? And another source of ESD would be someone handling the cable and/or the sensors without proper ESD protection.

Comment: it's more rugged than the cmos parts, but nothing survives a direct hit. using DIP parts in sockets seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: for ESD protection perhaps 2 47K resistors in series between the bottom of R4 and the comparator input,  from the middle of that pair two diodes to the supply rails, that should survive most static discharges, even accidental shorts to the mains.

Comment: Would you use Schottky diodes or just regular small signal silicon diodes? The higher leakage current and lower maximum reverse voltage could be a problem with Schottky's.

Comment: A little typo - R1, R3 should be 2 KOhm.

Comment: ESD for sure say ESDALC6V1W5, it has 4 devices in the package.  @JasenСлаваУкраїні mentioned a resistor between the bottom of R4 and the comparator. I say make it smaller, like 100 ohms, then add a 100nf capacitor to ground. This is to reduce mechanical bounce.  Between that  and the comparator add the ESD  between the input and ground.